# Matrix equation $Z - {}^t Z =c A Z$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, transpose

I would like to solve the following matrix equation, with $Z$ as the unknown matrix,

$$
Z - {}^t Z = c \, \Gamma G Z
$$

where the matrices $\Gamma$ and $G$ are both symmetric and invertible and c is a constant.

So I wonder if anyone can tell me if it is possible to solve this equation or if i have to do it component by component, that i'd prefer to avoid.

Thank you

Comment: Why answer your question when you do not read the answers ?  cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347196/unusual-quadratic-matrix-equation

Comment: In fact, i read it but the answer did not helped me, so i don't know why you told me that i did not read it

Comment: OK, maybe you thought: "thanks my dog".

Comment: Not at all, and thank you for the time you spent for me. I was just checking your solution and than I was absorbed by something else and then never return on it because that was not the solution of my problem.
But sorry if was so disturbing for you, so thanks again.